# darle un parametro al archivo batch al llamarlo con cmd

Tags: batch

cuando uno llamas a un archivo batch y lo pones en la carpeta window/system32, Y pones un espacio puede pasar parametros. pero no se como acceder a ellos, ¿como puedo hacerlo?.

```
   ----archivo min.bat----
   echo %parametro%

  -----cmd------
   %user%>min esto_a_recivir
```

quisiera acceder a los parametros, ¿de que forma seria posible?

Answer (score 0):

no es tan dificil de lo que parece. Simplemente ponga el siguiente signo: `%` y el numero de parametro, cada espacio es un parametro distinto

```
   ----archivo min.bat----
    echo %1

    ------cmd------
    %user%>min hola
```